# Calling xml rpc service from java

Tags: java, python, xml, rpc

How can I call an xmlrpclib service from Java? I can call the service in Python like this:

```py
proxy = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://ip:port')
print proxy.my_method("foo","bar")
```

In Java I tried this:

```java
XmlRpcClient proxy = new XmlRpcClient();
XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();

config.setServerURL(new URL("http://ip:port"));
proxy.setConfig(config);

Object[] nd1 = {"foo", "bar"};
Object object = proxy.execute("my_method", nd1);
```

The execute call throws an expection because it can't find the method. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?